# scipy kde contour to probability

Tags: scipy, kde-plasma

I have created a bivariate gaussian using the scipy.state kde library:

k = kde.gaussian_kde(data.T)

However I don't understand how the contours or z values relate to the probability of a new data point falling within those contours,

n[generated distribution with contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAyp4.png)

I would like to be able to define a contour with the equivalent of p=0.001, or put another way a contour defining 99.9% of expected observations.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking for the generalization of the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) for a multivariate case (2D)? but not defined with `P( X < x, Y < y)` (lower left quarter of the plane), and rather by using area inside contour of iso-density?